# Get attributes from module imported with star

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

A python script needs a per-user configuration to override (redefine) "default" assignments (e.g. `path = "local/path/"`) which could by done by importing a custom module's attributes  with `from custom_settings import *`. I would like to output the ones that are being changed by the custom module.

From within `custom_settings` its attributes can be obtained with [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir), e.g. `", ".join( (a for a in dir() if not a.startswith("__") ) )`.
How can this be done from the importing script if the imported module attributes are bound to the existing namespace?

Comment: Dear downvoter, what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the neatest solution, and it seems painfully redundant, but you could always simply:

```
from custom_settings import *
import custom_settings
overridden = ", ".join(a for a in dir(custom_settings) if not a.startswith("__"))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work as it does not overwrite the attributes in the existing namespace. I.e. it will create `custom_settings.path`, but not `path`

Comment: @handle Right. you can do *both*

Comment: Ah. Now I get the redundant.